# Comprobar igualdad de dos ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, comparaciones

Tengo dos ArrayList de objetos (usando Java),  cada objeto con varios atributos de distinto tipo. Quisiera saber si estos dos ArrayList contienen los mismos objetos (ni más ni menos), con los mismos valores. El orden es indiferente.

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
ArrayList<Producto>productoRec=new ArrayList<(Producto.recuperarArray());  
for(Producto e : productoRec){  
    if(e!=null){
        System.out.println(e); 
    }
}
for(Producto e : producto){
    if(e!=null){
    System.out.println(e); 
    } 
}
if(producto.equals(productoRec)){ 
    ES.msgln("Los ArrayList son iguales.");  
}else{
    ES.msgln("Los ArrayList son diferentes.");
}
```

Al ejecutar obtengo:

Fruta: Código de producto: 3 
Nombre del producto: n (no es fruta de temporada)

Fruta: Código de producto: 3 
Nombre del producto: n (no es fruta de temporada)

Los ArrayList son diferentes.
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 3 seconds)

No sé qué estoy haciendo mal, pero se ve claro que los ArrayList son iguales, pero sin embargo la respuesta al ejecutarlo es que son diferentes.

Comment: Hola Raúl, bienvenido. Te faltaría añadir el codigo que has intentado y por qué no cumple su función. Te da fallos o problemas?  Recuerda pasar por [ask] para aprender a formular mejores preguntas. Un saludo

Comment: Hay muchas formas distintas de hacer esto, ¿has intentando algo??

Comment: Hola, pido disculpas por hacer una pregunta tan amplia y sin código. No había visto el apartado que me indicas "Cómo preguntar". Voy a estudiarme bien este apartado antes de incluir nada más, para que la pregunta sea formulada lo mejor posible. Muchas gracias por las respuestas.

Comment: Raul, no te preocupes que para eso estamos, para indicar qué se puede mejorar heheh y tampoco te asustes del estado "en espera". he visto tu codigo y he votado para reabrirla. un saludo

Comment: Ambas listas son objetos distintos aunque tengan el mismo contenido, por eso te muestra que son diferentes.

Comment: Voy a probar el código que ha enviado lois6b, a ver si me funciona. Muchas gracias por contestar (y tan rápido).

Comment: He probado el método de lois6b y no me ha funcionado, luego he probado if((producto.contains(productoRec))&&(productoRec.contains(producto))){  que tampoco me ha funcionado. Por último he probado  if((producto.toString()).equals(productoRec.toString())){ que sí me ha funcionado, aunque parece un poco extraño. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

he intentado adaptar el método de lois6b, pero no consigo que funcione. Lo único que me ha funcionado, aunque no parece muy ortodoxo es aplicar el método toStrig a cada ArrayList y comparar los resultados:

```
ArrayList<Producto>productoRec=new ArrayList<(Producto.recuperarArray());  
for(Producto e : productoRec){  
    if(e!=null){
        System.out.println(e); 
    }
}
for(Producto e : producto){
    if(e!=null){
    System.out.println(e); 
    } 
}
if(producto.toString()).equals(productoRec.toString())){ 
    ES.msgln("Los ArrayList son iguales.");  
}else{
    ES.msgln("Los ArrayList son diferentes.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Si no quieres modificar los contenidos de tus listas, lo mejor sería volcar el contenido de las mismas en un `Map` y luego ir revisando si realmente existen en ambos lugares. Nota: para esto, es necesario que tu clase implemente los métodos `equals` y `hashCode`.

```
public <T> boolean igualdad(List<T> lista1, List<T> lista2) {
    //check inicial: si las listas son la misma referencia
    //o ambas son nulas, entonces no comparar nada
    if (lista1 == lista2 || (lista1 == null && lista2 == null) {
        return true;
    }
    //segundo check: si una de las listas es nula, no comparar
    if ( (lista1 == null && lista2 != null) ||
            (lista1 !=null && lista2 == null) ) {
        return false;
    }

    Map<Producto, Integer> mapFuente = new HashMap<>();
    for (T elem : lista1) {
        Integer contador = mapFuente.get(elem);
        mapFuente.put(elem, contador == null ? 0 : contador + 1);
    }
    for (T elem : lista2) {
        Integer contador = mapFuente.get(elem);
        if (contador != null) {
            if (contador > 1) {
                mapFuente.put(elem, contador - 1);
            } else {
                mapFuente.remove(elem);
            }
        }
    }
    return map.isEmpty();
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, voy a intentar esta solución. He publicado la solución que se me ha ocurrido (que de momento me funciona) casi a la vez que tu publicabas ésta.

Answer (score -2):

Lo más sencillo para comparar dos `ArrayList` es utilizar el método `sort` de la clase `Collection`, que ya lo implementa la interfaz ArrayList, para ordenar los ArrayList y comparar después si son iguales:

```
public  boolean equalLists(List<String> a, List<String> b){     
    // comprobar que tienen el mismo tamaño y que no son nulos
    if ((a.size() != b.size()) || (a == null && b!= null) || (a != null && b== null)){
        return false;
    }

    if (a == null && b == null) return true;

    // ordenar las ArrayList y comprobar que son iguales          
    Collections.sort(a);
    Collections.sort(b);      
    return a.equals(b);
}
```

Esta solución está sacada de [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19155283/simple-way-to-compare-2-arraylists)

Comment: Por favor, siempre que copies la respuesta de SO intenta poner la referencia por si le vale en contexto: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19155283/simple-way-to-compare-2-arraylists

Comment: Hola Erlantz. El autor aun no ha presentado el codigo intentado asi que por el momento es como si no hubiera hecho nada. Responder a preguntas demasiado amplias no es constructivo porque se promueve el tipo de preguntas de "hacedme esta tarea". Te recomiendo borrarla hasta que el autor edite su pregunta y despues, darle a recuperar . Un saludo

Comment: Claro @JoseD.Jurado ahora la añado

Comment: @lois6b no me importa borrarla pero, ¿y si puede ayudar a alguien más?

Comment: @ErlantzCalvo puede que esas personas encuentren la solucion que tu mismo has encontrado. Si quieres, puedo poner el enlace en los comentarios.

Comment: Aun así la respuesta está mal, la comparación con nulls hay que hacerlo lo primero, en ese caso si cualquiera de las dos listas es null la pregunta por size() hará saltar un nullPointerException.

Comment: @lois6b si la solución es una traducción/copia del sitio en inglés o de cualquier otro lugar de la red, se debe brindar la atribución propia en el cuerpo de la pregunta.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. He intentado adaptar el código a mi caso (pasando los ArrayList a List, para que no me de error Collection), pero no he conseguido que funcione. No he respondido con el código que he intentado porque no sé cómo hacerlo.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza si, lo se. por eso José le pidió al usuario que editara la pregunta .